# Typescript restriction of nested objects

Tags: typescript

I have following general-purpose type definition:

```
export interface genericParameter {
    [k: string]: any
}
```

Is there a clever way to restrict such signature from assigning nested objects? For example I'd be happy to accept this type:

```
{
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 123,
}
```

But not this:

```
{
  Obj1: {prop1: 'val1'},
  Obj2: {prop2: 123},
}
```

Thanks for any help!

---EDIT---

Considering following:

```
[k: string]: string | number | /* unmanageable list */
```

Seems not an option I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell typescript that can't be of a given type (not without done conditional types and a function anyway). In this case though, the list of primitive types is pretty short, so we can just enumerate the allowed types in a union

```
export interface genericParameter {
    [k: string]: number | string | boolean
}
```

**Edit**

As @t-j-crowder points out, if you are going to use this type in many places, you might want to declare a type alias for the union (especially since what is a primitive may evolve over time with the addition of `BigInt` in the future)

```
type primitive = number | string | boolean;
export interface genericParameter {
    [k: string]: primitive
}
```